# Unable to create plot in external window in Canopy IPython Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, inline, ipython, enthought

I just started using Canopy, and it's very nice, but I am unable to create a figure in an external window in [iPython Notebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Notebook). I would expect

```
plot(rand(100))
```

in the notebook to create a new window, as it does when I use the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) version launched with "ipython notebook --pylab", but the figure is instead inlined when created in Canopy. The same command in the qtconsole in Canopy *does* create the figure in a new window as I would like it to. Looking through the Canopy/IPython source code for appearances of 'inline' and 'pylab', inlined figures appear to be hard-coded somehow (the comments mention something about compatibility).

Is there is a way around this, where I can still create figures in new windows from the IPython notebook? The inlined figures are unsatisfactory for my work.

Answer (score 2):

The preference option only changes the [pylab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib#Comparison_with_MATLAB) backend for the embedded Python pane. To change the backend for a notebook, you will have to do it manually for each notebook, by evaluating:

```
%pylab qt
```

Due to a possible issue in matplotlib, if this fails with the error saying matplotlib is not installed, you need to set `QT_API=pyside` in your environment.

I'm not sure what your operating system is, so, an all platform solution would be, running something like inside your notebook:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyside'
%pylab qt
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit --> Preferences --> Python and select a diffrent PyLab backend